# Are there infinite solutions to the complex equation $z^x =27$ when $x$ is irrational?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, irrational-numbers

Example: $$z^\pi =27$$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$z=27^{\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)}=(r \, e^{i\phi+k2\pi i})^{\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)}=r \, e^{\frac{i\phi}{\pi}+k2 i}$$
for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I believe this should mean that the equation has infinite solutions because
$$\frac{i\phi}{\pi} + 2 \, k \, i \neq t \pi$$
for $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct but your proof is not.